# Dead-letter Queue

Tags: ibm-mq, dead-letter

my question is about WebSphere MQ's Dead-letter.

How I can view on ISPF the queue manager's dead-letter?

Each queue manager has a default dead-letter queue or I need to define it?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

A queue manager does not have a dead-letter queue by default. You must tell the queue manager where its dead-letter queue is. The CSQINP2 samples (if you use them) define a QLOCAL called ++qmgr++.DEAD.QUEUE - see sample CSQ4INYG. If you use that sample and do the search and replace on the ++qmgr++ text, you may have the queue defined. But, you still need to tell the queue manager to use that queue as its dead-letter queue.

To view whether a queue manager has a dead-letter queue, you need to issue the following command:-

```
DISPLAY QMGR DEADQ
```

Alternatively you can view the same information on the MQ ISPF panels by

- Chosing option 1. List or Display
- For Object type MANAGER
- Hit enter, and view the first page of queue manager details. Just below 'Description' and 'Default transmission queue' you will see 'Dead-letter queue'

To alter it, use option 3. from the ISPF panels or issue the following command:-

```
ALTER QMGR DEADQ(CSQ1.DEAD.QUEUE)
```

Changing the above queue name to be correct for your queue manager.

You can use any named queue you wish, you do not have to follow the convention used in the CSQ4INYG sample, but I would recommend having a name that indicates the purpose of the queue clearly.